# How to disable WebRTC in GeckoFX C#

Tags: javascript, c#, gecko, geckofx

I'm trying to disable WebRTC functionality in GeckoFx.

I've heard about media.peerconnection.enabled. but i'm unable to find how to
set it up programmatically using C#.net.

I was able to disable it by going to about:config page manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See GeckoPreferences.Default or GeckoPreferences.User:

```
GeckoPreferences.Default["media.peerconnection.enabled"] = false;
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. :) This One Helped Me. :)